# How to configure my manifes in Xamarin for Android V12

Tags: xamarin, google-play, manifest

My current manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.cecop.cecop" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="132" android:versionName="14.00">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application android:label="cecop" android:icon="@drawable/cecop">
        <!--Especifique el número de versión de Google Play Services en el manifiesto y la clave de Google Maps V2 API. -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyBLH0HotP0r5yfuX8xFESZhM5TS0PcluKs" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <!-- Needed for Android >= Nougat for file access -->
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.cecop.cecop.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <service android:name="com.cecop.cecop.ServicioSegundoPlano" android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In the service and main activity I have this attributes

```
  [Service(Exported = true, Name = "com.cecop.cecop.ServicioSegundoPlano")]
    public class ServicioStartForeground : Service
    {
     ...
    }

    [Activity(Label = "Cecop", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {...
    }
```

As I write in the manifest so you don't get the error in the publication on Google Play?

*You have uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that has an activity, an alias of activity, a service or an emission receiver with atnts filter, but without establishing the Android property: exported. This file cannot be installed on Android 12 or later versions.*

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define anything in AndroidManifest.xml if you are using the `[Service]` attribute. Xamarin generates this for you.

The only change you need to make on Android 12, is that you need to add whether a Service is exported or not. Default should be `false` unless you need to access it from another App than yours.

If you are using something like Xamarin.Essentials or other libraries that also contain services, make sure they are up to date and also follow these rules about adding Exported property on their services.